# building remmina teamviewer plugin ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, dependencies, 20.04, make, remmina

I am trying to build the remmina teamviewer plugin in my fresh ubuntu 20.04 install after getting an unspecified unmet dependency trying to install the remmina-plugin-teamviewer_1.0.0.2-1_amd64.deb from https://www.muflone.com/remmina-plugin-teamviewer/english/download.

unfortunately i can't build as i get an error msg on copying the plugin source files to the remmina-plugin-to-build directory:

```
cp --recursive remmina-plugin-teamviewer CMakeLists.txt remmina-plugin-builder-1.3.0.0/remmina-plugin-to-build/
```

error msg: 
cp: cannot stat 'remmina-plugin-teamviewer': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'CMakeLists.txt': No such file or directory

i tried replacing "remmina-plugin-teamviewer" with "remmina-plugin-builder-1.3.0.0", (knowing that it wouldn't work but tried anyways), but that obviously created the following error msg:

cp: cannot copy a directory, 'remmina-plugin-builder-1.3.0.0', into itself, 'remmina-plugin-builder-1.3.0.0/remmina-plugin-to-build/remmina-plugin-builder-1.3.0.0'
cp: cannot stat 'CMakeLists.txt': No such file or directory

i need this step to get to be able to build the make file and i really don't understand what this is meant to do.

can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks ahead.

Matthieu

Comment: What was wrong with downloading binary deb-package from https://github.com/muflone/remmina-plugin-teamviewer/releases ? Are you sure that TeamViewer API wont change since 2014?

Comment: nothing really.. except it being from 2014 and having the unmet dependency with the same .deb version i looked into newer versions available hoping that that would solve it. which just craeted a diff problem. but never mind it got solved.

Answer (score 2):

No need to struggle with building from source on 20.04. Take a look at this:

```
$ ls -1
remmina-plugin-teamviewer_1.0.0.2-1_amd64.deb
teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb ./remmina-plugin-teamviewer_1.0.0.2-1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'teamviewer' instead of './teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'remmina-plugin-teamviewer' instead of './remmina-plugin-teamviewer_1.0.0.2-1_amd64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
Suggested packages:
  qt5-qmltooling-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
  remmina-plugin-teamviewer teamviewer
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16,1 MB/30,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 141 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: oddly enough that worked. I have no clue why this worked now and it didn't before as i think i did exactly the same. except that when i did it before there was, as said an undefined unmet dependency. But i got it installed.. now just try to see to get it to work. Many thanks !